# Looping Buttons and alerting values

Tags: javascript

Why wont this console log the values on click?! its coming up undefined.
as this isn't a arrow function this should be the div it clicks on?

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    console.log(this.value)
  })
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="box" value="box1" name='test'>1</div>
     <div class="box" value="box2">2</div>
     <div class="box" value="box3">3</div>
     <div class="box" value="box4">4</div>
     <div class="box" value="box5">5</div>
     <div class="box" value="box6">6</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you verified that 'boxes' is populated ?  What does alert(boxes.length) display?

Comment: Just as an aside, the first debugging step should be to try `console.log(this)` instead, which will confirm that it logs the correct `<div>`. The next step is to figure out that `<div>`s apparently don't have a `.value` attribute, which only exists for a `HTMLInputElement` respectively the interface they're using.

Comment: Btw, you can use `data-value="box1"` instead, they way you can grab the value using `this.dataset.value`

Comment: Here's my take btw: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/szt9gwvn/

Answer (score 2):

`div` does not have any property called `value`.You can check it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). If you still want to use it then use `getAttribute`

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
  })

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box" value="box1" name='test'>1</div>
  <div class="box" value="box2">2</div>
  <div class="box" value="box3">3</div>
  <div class="box" value="box4">4</div>
  <div class="box" value="box5">5</div>
  <div class="box" value="box6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you the getAttribute works fine, but I was under the impression "this" would work for anything! so anything like this I would always need to set "getAttribute" ??

Comment: @Lee No, see my comment to your question. Using `this` is fine, but `this.value` only works for `<input>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this for the value in the `div` :

```
   console.log(this.innerHTML)
```

For the value the  in attribute

```
   console.log(this.getAttribute('value'))
```

Comment: It won't work because there is no `value` property on HTMLDivElement type

Comment: OP doesn't want `.innerHTML` but the `value` attribute in the tag.

Comment: Okay I got you ; Updated again

Comment: Now it's just brk's answer without the snippet.

Comment: brk got it first ;)